# How do I select a model in SQLAlchemy by the number of relationships it has, and then order by the same number?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I can easily select by the value of a relationship's field, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to select and order by the number of relationships.  Specifically, what I want to do is select all users with at least one post, and then order by the users with the most posts.  I want to do this without storing an extra field in the database as a post count, or selecting all of them and sorting them manually.

Something like

```
User.query.filter(len(User.posts.all()) > 0).all()
```

would be ideal for example, though this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [having()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.having)

```
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(User).\
        join(User.posts).\
        group_by(User).\
        having(func.count(Post.id) > 0).\
        order_by(func.count(Post.id).desc())
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.